# ZF-Rest $event->getRouteMatch() is null when extending RestController

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I'm using the `zf-rest` composer package in my project.

This is the `create` method in my resource file.

```
public function create($data)
{
    var_dump($e->getRouteMatch()->getParams()); 
    // all URL params are listed here with the correct values
    die();
}
```

I've now extended `RestController` to `CustomRestController` and added

```
'controller_class' => CustomRestController::class
```

to the config file.

Now, `var_dump($event->getRouteMatch());` is `null` inside the Resource classs.

In `public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)`, using

```
$eventManager->attach(
    MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, 
    function($e) {
        // I can still read `$e->getRouteMatch()->getParams()`
    } 
);
```

Any suggestion on how to deal with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

The root problem is `RestParametersListener`. It's using FQCNs like:

```
$listener = $events->attach(
    RestController::class,
    // more params
);
```

So extending the RestController causes these `attach`/`detach` calls to avoid the new controller.

A clean fix was to extend `RestParametersListener` to `CustomRestParametersListener` and change the controller classes inside.

After extending this, I've also added it in `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'ZF\Rest\RestParametersListener' => CustomRestParametersListener::class,
    ],
    // ...
]
```

---

**Initial answer**:

Found a workaround until issues 102 and 103 get fixed by the zf-rest dev team

In my `CustomRestController`:

```
try {
    $this->manuallyInjectRouteMatch(); // added this line
    $value = $this->getResource()->create($data);
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    return $this->createApiProblemFromThrowable($e);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return $this->createApiProblemFromException($e);
}
```

Where:

```
/**
 * By using this factory instead of the default one and by creating a CastorRestController
 * instead of RestController, the routeMatch property is "lost".
 * Manually injecting it so we have access to it inside the *Resource class
 */
private function manuallyInjectRouteMatch()
{
    $r = new \ReflectionProperty(Resource::class, 'routeMatch');
    $r->setAccessible(true);
    $r->setValue($this->getResource(), $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch());
}
```

Also, the `manuallyInjectRouteMatch` needs to be called for the other REST methods as well